# Finding the symmetric points of $a\in\mathbb{C}$ with respect to the lines which bisect the angles between the coordinate axes.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find the symmetric points of a with respect to the lines which
> bisect the angles between the coordinate axes.

I am not entirely sure whether the question asks to find the symmetries w.r.t. lines $f(t) = (1 + i)t, g(t) = (1 - i)t, t \in \mathbb{R}$ or between lines bisecting the angle between the axis and $a$. In either case, could we just use both complex and "group" conjugation to first rotate the axis of symmetry to the real axis, then perform a complex conjugate and lastly revert the rotation. Specifically, let $b$ and $c$ be the correct two points. Then, the two symmetric points of $a$ w.r.t. lines passing through $b$ and $c$ are in order $a_1 = \overline{ae^{i\mathrm{Arg}(b)}}e^{-i\mathrm{Arg}(b)}$ and $a_1 = \overline{ae^{i\mathrm{Arg}(c)}}e^{-i\mathrm{Arg}(c)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Sick Series.

---

I am interpreting the question to mean that if $a = (x + iy)$ that the desired points are $(y + ix)$ and $(-y - ix).$

That is, in the analogous $\Bbb{R^2}$, I am imagining that first, the point $a$ is rotated about the line $y = x$ and then the point $a$ is rotated about the line $y = -x$.

An easy way of thinking about this is that you want the slope between $a$ and the first point to be $-1$ and the slope between $a$ and the second point to be $+1$.

As an additional shortcut, note that when each of the rotations are performed, the distance between the resulting point and the origin must be the same as the original distance between point $a$ and the origin.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment of Sick Series.

> How did you reason that the points should be $±(y+ix)$ for $(x+iy)$?

Good question, and one that highlights the weakness of the exposition of my original answer.  The analysis is difficult to communicate without including diagrams, which are a lot of trouble for me.

I regard the problem as one that involves the following:

- Real Analysis, via $\Bbb{R^2}$, rather than the Complex Plane.
- Cartesian coordinates, rather than polar coordinates.
- [Trigonometry :: Analytical Geometry] rather than Algebra.

Consider the question, of how to determine the affect of rotating the point $A = (x_1, y_1)$ along the line $y = x$.  The resulting point $B = (x_2, y_2)$ is uniquely determined by the following constraints:

- The line segment $\overline{AB}$ must be perpendicular to the line $y = x.$
- Assume that $\overline{AB}$ intersects the line $y = x$ at the point $C$.  Then, you must have that the length of $\overline{AC}$ equals the length of $\overline{BC}$.

Let $O$ denote the origin, whose Cartesian coordinates are $(0,0)$.  Then, from the above constraints, you have that $\triangle ACO$ is congruent to $\triangle BCO$.  This implies that the length of line segment $\overline{AO}$ equals the length of line segment $\overline{BO}$.

It is clear that setting $B$ equal to the point whose Cartesian coordinates are $(y_1,x_1)$ satisfies the two constraints.  That is, the  slope of $\overline{AB}$ then equals $(-1)$ and the length of line segment $\overline{BO}$ then equals the length of line segment $\overline{AO}$.  Therefore, the solution $B = (y_1, x_1)$ must be unique.

---

In a very similar fashion, consider the other question of of how to determine the affect of rotating the point $A = (x_1, y_1)$ along the line $y = -x$.  The resulting point $D = (x_3, y_3)$ is uniquely determined by the following constraints:

- The line segment $\overline{AD}$ must be perpendicular to the line $y = -x.$
- Assume that $\overline{AD}$ intersects the line $y = -x$ at the point $E$.  Then, you must have that the length of $\overline{AE}$ equals the length of $\overline{DE}$.

Then, from the above constraints, you have that $\triangle AEO$ is congruent to $\triangle DEO$.  This implies that the length of line segment $\overline{AO}$ equals the length of line segment $\overline{EO}$.

It is clear that setting $D$ equal to the point whose Cartesian coordinates are $(-y_1,-x_1)$ satisfies the two constraints.  That is, the  slope of $\overline{AD}$ then equals $(+1)$ and the length of line segment $\overline{DO}$ then equals the length of line segment $\overline{AO}$.  Therefore, the solution $D = (-y_1, -x_1)$ must be unique.

---

As a secondary, somewhat informal visualization approach, visualize what happens if point $A = (x_1,y_1)$ happens to have $x_1 = 0$ and $y_1 > 0$.  Visualize the effect of rotating point $A$, first along the line $y = x$, and then along the line $y = -x$.

Comment: How did you reason that the points should be $\pm(y + ix)$ for $(x + iy)$? I am asking because in e.g. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xqth07m8pv I am not sure what is the angle the black and red line (segments) should bisect?

Comment: @SickSeries First, see the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.  Then, re-read the original question and ask yourself whether I have misinterpreted what the original question intended.  If I have misinterpreted it, please leave me another comment, explaining as carefully as you can, what you think that the question is really asking.

Comment: @SickSeries To restate the issue, what does the following mean: "Find the symmetric points of a with respect to the lines which bisect the angles between the coordinate axes"?  Which angles?  Is it the $(90^\circ)$ angles between the $x$ and $y$ axis that are supposed to be bisected?  Alternatively, is it some other angles that are supposed to be bisected?  If so, which ones?  Please explain, **as carefully as you can**, what you think that the question is asking, and I will then add an Addendum-2, if needed, to attack the alternative interpretation of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum! As per the exact semantics of the question, I honestly don't know what interpretation is correct. The question I wrote is a verbatim copy from my CA book, *Complex Analysis, 3rd ed., Lars Ahlfors* pp. 15 ex 1. I did not manage to find a similar exercise online, nor a complete solution manual for the book. But since your approach is more constructive than mine, I think that in the light of all evidence, it is correct enough.